# How long does a ban from editing after too many rejected edits last?

Tags: support

I did some edits to remove noise (e.g. https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/541897) in the "spirit" of askubuntu.com (where such an edit would be approved with 95 % probability in my experience although I don't know if that's good or not), but most of them were rejected which caused a block for editing. There's no info how long it will last or what I could do other than wait.

I don't disagree with the rejections. I was just trying to get n*2 rep to be able to place a bounty without loosing reviewing privileges and it wasn't right. I learned my lesson. The ban isn't for eternity, right?

Comment: The suggested edit you linked to is in fact a valid edit (though I would not have removed "any thoughts?" as that's really part of the question) and I would have approved it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: The ban is for 7 days; details are available [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141325/295684) indicates that the edit ban will be in place for the seven days after your last rejected edit.

That said, cruft-removing edits are a good thing and should be approved, *as long as* there are no other notable issues with the post. In the case of the suggestion you linked, you should have also fixed the capitalization of "Task Scheduler" and maybe given the question a more descriptive title. Such an edit would definitely have been accepted.

Comment: I suggested better provision of information at http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11577/provide-duration-of-editing-ban.

Answer (score 5):

According to your profile, your ban should be gone in ~10 hours from when I posted this.

I kinda think the problem here was the edit was somewhat trivial. Some handy things to do here would have been to merge in the additional information in the comments, make sure you fixed *other* things, and well, make sure your edits are less than trivial.

Also suggested edits are a *terribly* inefficient way to accrue rep. I find the best reason for editing is 'this typo annoys me' rather than a way to nickle and dime rep.