# Banned from suggesting edits

Tags: discussion

I've been temporarily banned from suggesting edits. I've been trying to find out how long that will last, and none of the help docs I've found have described it.

I've checked:

[How long does a ban from editing after too many rejected edits last?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11573/how-long-does-a-ban-from-editing-after-too-many-rejected-edits-last) and

[I am unable to suggest edits even after the seven-day ban period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141324/i-am-unable-to-suggest-edits-even-after-the-seven-day-ban-period/141325#141325)

Most of what I've seen says it should last for seven days, but I'm still unable to suggest edits even after the seven-day ban period.

I accept the ban and I'll work to improve, but I also want to know how the consequences last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ban is due to expire in 8 days from now, after which you will again be able to suggest edits again.

Please bear in mind the advice I have given you in the [chat room you created](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40333230#4033), specifically that many of your edits were very minor and some required correction after your edits.